# Resource for comparing javascript web frameworks

Tags: javascript, resources, benchmarking

I'm trying to find a resource that has benchmarks of Dojo, jquery, mootools, etc of the most popular javascript libraries.

Comment: I encourage you to pay more attention to the programming style imposed (or "suggested" maybe) by each framework before you worry about performance. Also important: documentation quality, comprehensiveness of functionality, bug list size, community resources, etc. Most modern Javascript frameworks have good performance and even share some critical parts.

Comment: Yes I agree all of those should be taken into consideration. I just wanted to ask about performance as to not overload a question and I really couldn't find an abundance of information on performance. Thank you for the tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a comparison flash chart.

http://www.swivel.com/charts/12485-jquery-1-4-2-taskspeed-performance-comparisons

I like jQuery. I've read that stackoverflow is using jQuery.

Comment: If you view the source of this page, you will indeed be sure that they are using JQuery ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check out here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks

Comment: This is a nice resource. I was looking more for benchmarks however.